# android - Handling aspect ratio on openGL Renderer for Camera Orientation Landscape

Tags: android, opengl-es, orientation, opengl-es-2.0, landscape

I am rendering camera data on my GLSurfaceView. Everything work fine . But the problem is the image stretch a bit in landscape mood. I have read this and tried that solution [http://www.learnopengles.com/understanding-opengls-matrices](http://www.learnopengles.com/understanding-opengls-matrices/) . Please the check the "Adjusting to the screen’s aspect ratio" part of that link. I tried that solution . my code for that solution are attached below. These code are from part of my `Renderer` class which implements `GLSurfaceView.Renderer` interface :

```
private float[] vertices;
private float[] verticesFrontCameraPortrait = new float[]{1.f, -1.f, -1.f, -1.f, -1.f, 1.f, 1.f, 1.f};
private float[] verticesFrontCamera_90_Degree_Right = new float[]{-1.f, -1.f, -1.f, 1.f, 1.f, 1.f, 1.f, -1.f,};
private float[] verticesFrontCamera_270_Degree_right = new float[]{1.f, 1.f, 1.f, -1.f, -1.f, -1.f, -1.f, 1.f,};

 @Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl10, int width, int height) {
    GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    float aspectRatio = (float) width / (float) height;
    Matrix.orthoM(vertices, 0, -aspectRatio, aspectRatio, -1, 1, -1, 1);
}
```

My `vertices` variable hold the reference of any of the three vertice matrices according to device configuration. That works fine totally. But the problem occurs if try the work on `onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl10, int width, int height)`
method. It crush my program saying `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExceptio` . But if i don't use these two lines :

```
    float aspectRatio = (float) width / (float) height;
    Matrix.orthoM(vertices, 0, -aspectRatio, aspectRatio, -1, 1, -1, 1);
```

everything work fine but the video/camera image data's are stretched on landscape mood. I don't want stretched image that are rendered on my GLSurfaceView.

Here is my full `Renderer` class .

/**
 * IMPORTANT - Please read before changing
 *

* This class render a NV21 (YV12) image byte array in GlSurfaceView using OpenGl.
 * NV21 image format has 12 bits per pixel out of which 8 bits are for luminance (Y) and 4 bits
 * are for chrominance (UV). So yBuffer size is same and uvBuffer size is of half
 * of number of pixels. yTexture height and widht are also same as image height and width.
 * First 2/3 of the input image array are Y values and last 1/3 are uv in the
 * order v0u0v1u1... (altering v and u values) so on. So GL_LUMINANCE and GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA format
 * are used to pass yBuffer and uvBuffer respectively and fragment_shader takes U value from alpha channel
 * and V value from red channel (could be green or blue channel with same result). uvTexture height
 * and width are also 1/4 of the original image height and width
 *

* GL_TEXTURE0 + 1 (GL_TEXTURE1) and GL_TEXTURE0 + 2 (GL_TEXTURE2) must be used for yTexture and uvTexture.
 * If GL_TEXTURE0 is used for yTexture, it doesn't work in some devices.
 */

```
public class VideoCallImageRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {
    private final String TAG = "VideoCallImageRenderer";
    private int cameraType; // 0 for backcamera, 1 for front camera, 2 for opponent camera
    private Context context;
    private int shaderProgram;
    short[] indices = new short[]{0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3};
    // y texture handle
    private int[] yTexture = new int[1];
    // uv texture handle
    private int[] uvTexture = new int[1];
    // texture coordinate and vertices buffers
    private FloatBuffer texCoordBuffer, vertexBuffer;
    // indices buffer
    private ShortBuffer indexBuffer;
    // y and uv texture buffers
    private ByteBuffer yBuffer, uvBuffer;
    // image height and width
    private int width = 0, height = 0;
    // true when a valid image data is set. default value false.
    private boolean render = false;
    // position attribute location handle in vertex shader
    private int positionLocation;
    // texture coordinate attribute location handle in vertex shader
    private int textureCoordinateLocation;
    // y_texture sampler2D location handle in fragment shader
    private int yTextureLocation;
    // uv_texture sampler2D location handle in fragment shader
    private int uvTextureLocation;

final private float bytePerPixel = 1.5f;
/*This value of vertices are changed to roatate the image: explanation
let 1.f, 1.f = A
   -1.f, 1.f = B
   -1.f, -1.f= C
    1.f, -1.f = D

    SO ABCD = Back camera in normal stage
    if we want to rotate 90 degre  right then value will be DABC
     if we want to rotate 90 degre left then value will be BCDA

private float[] vertices = new float[]{
        1.f, -1.f,
        -1.f, -1.f,
        -1.f, 1.f,
        1.f, 1.f

};
     */

private float[] vertices;
private float[] verticesPortrait;
private float[] vertices_90_Degree_Right;
private float[] vertices_270_Degree_Right;


private int currentDeviceOrientation = -1;

private float[] verticesFrontCameraPortrait = new float[]{1.f, -1.f, -1.f, -1.f, -1.f, 1.f, 1.f, 1.f};
private float[] verticesFrontCamera_90_Degree_Right = new float[]{-1.f, -1.f, -1.f, 1.f, 1.f, 1.f, 1.f, -1.f,};
private float[] verticesFrontCamera_270_Degree_right = new float[]{1.f, 1.f, 1.f, -1.f, -1.f, -1.f, -1.f, 1.f,};


private float[] verticesBackCameraPortrait = new float[]{1.f, 1.f, -1.f, 1.f, -1.f, -1.f, 1.f, -1.f};
private float[] verticesBackCamera_90_Degree_Right = new float[]{1.f, -1.f, 1.f, 1.f, -1.f, 1.f, -1.f, -1.f,};
private float[] verticesBackCamera_270_Degree_Right = new float[]{-1.f, 1.f, -1.f, -1.f, 1.f, -1.f, 1.f, 1.f,};

private float[] verticesOpponentCamera = new float[]{1.f, 1.f, 1.f, -1.f, -1.f, -1.f, -1.f, 1.f};
private float[] verticeOpponentCamera_90_Degree_Right = new float[]{1.f, -1.f, -1.f, -1.f, -1.f, 1.f, 1.f, 1.f,};
private float[] verticeOpponentCamera_270_Degree_Right = new float[]{-1.f, 1.f, 1.f, 1.f, 1.f, -1.f, -1.f, -1.f,};

private float[] texCoords = new float[]{
        0.f, 0.f,
        0.f, 1.f,
        1.f, 1.f,
        1.f, 0.f
};

public VideoCallImageRenderer(Context context, int cameraType) {
    this.context = context;
    // initialize texture coordinate buffer
    this.cameraType = cameraType;
    if (cameraType == 0) {
        verticesPortrait = verticesBackCameraPortrait;
        vertices_90_Degree_Right = verticesBackCamera_90_Degree_Right;
        vertices_270_Degree_Right = verticesBackCamera_270_Degree_Right;
    } else if (cameraType == 1) {
        verticesPortrait = verticesFrontCameraPortrait;
        vertices_90_Degree_Right = verticesFrontCamera_90_Degree_Right;
        vertices_270_Degree_Right = verticesFrontCamera_270_Degree_right;
    } else {
        verticesPortrait = verticesOpponentCamera;
        vertices_90_Degree_Right = verticeOpponentCamera_90_Degree_Right;
        vertices_270_Degree_Right = verticeOpponentCamera_270_Degree_Right;
    }
    ByteBuffer tcbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(texCoords.length * 4);
    tcbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    texCoordBuffer = tcbb.asFloatBuffer();
    texCoordBuffer.put(texCoords);
    texCoordBuffer.position(0);

    // initialize vertices buffer
    vertices = verticesPortrait;
    ByteBuffer vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4);
    vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    vertexBuffer = vbb.asFloatBuffer();
    vertexBuffer.put(vertices);
    vertexBuffer.position(0);

    // initialize indices buffer
    ByteBuffer ibb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(indices.length * 2);
    ibb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    indexBuffer = ibb.asShortBuffer();
    indexBuffer.put(indices);
    indexBuffer.position(0);
}

public void resetVertex(float[] new_vertices) {
    Constants.debugLog(TAG, "resetVertex");
    ByteBuffer vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(new_vertices.length * 4);
    vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    vertexBuffer = vbb.asFloatBuffer();
    vertexBuffer.put(new_vertices);
    vertexBuffer.position(0);
}

public void setImageBuffer(final byte[] imageBytes, int height, int width, int iDeviceOrientation) {
    // reinitialize texture buffers if width or height changes
    Constants.debugLog(TAG, "setImageBuffer device Orientation == " + iDeviceOrientation);
    if (currentDeviceOrientation == -1) {
        currentDeviceOrientation = iDeviceOrientation;
    }
    if (iDeviceOrientation != currentDeviceOrientation) {
        currentDeviceOrientation = iDeviceOrientation;
        switch (currentDeviceOrientation) {
            case 0:
                vertices = verticesPortrait;
                resetVertex(vertices);
                break;
            case 1:
                vertices = vertices_90_Degree_Right;
                resetVertex(vertices);
                break;
            case 3:
                vertices = vertices_270_Degree_Right;
                resetVertex(vertices);
                break;
        }

    }


    final boolean resolutionChanged = this.width != width || this.height != height;
    if (resolutionChanged) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        final int numberOfPixels = this.height * this.width;
        this.yBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(numberOfPixels);
        this.yBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        this.uvBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(numberOfPixels / 2);
        this.uvBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    }

    this.render = updateYUVBuffers(imageBytes);
}

private boolean updateYUVBuffers(final byte[] imageBytes) {
    final int numberOfPixels = this.height * this.width;

    final int numberOfExpectedBytes = (int) (numberOfPixels * this.bytePerPixel);
    if (imageBytes != null && imageBytes.length != (int) (numberOfPixels * this.bytePerPixel)) {
        return false;
    }

    // put image bytes into texture buffers
    yBuffer.put(imageBytes, 0, numberOfPixels);
    yBuffer.position(0);
    uvBuffer.put(imageBytes, numberOfPixels, numberOfPixels / 2);
    uvBuffer.position(0);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl10, EGLConfig eglConfig) {
    createShader();
    positionLocation = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "a_position");
    textureCoordinateLocation = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "a_texCoord");

    // generate y texture
    GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    yTextureLocation = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "y_texture");
    GLES20.glGenTextures(1, yTexture, 0);
    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0 + 1);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, yTexture[0]);

    // generate uv texture
    GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    uvTextureLocation = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uv_texture");
    GLES20.glGenTextures(1, uvTexture, 0);
    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0 + 2);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, uvTexture[0]);

    // clear display color
    GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl10, int width, int height) {
    GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    float aspectRatio = (float) width / (float) height;
 Matrix.orthoM(vertices, 0, -aspectRatio, aspectRatio, -1, 1, -1, 1);
}

@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl10) {
    // clear display
    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    if (render) {
        GLES20.glUseProgram(shaderProgram);

        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(positionLocation, 2,
                GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
                0, vertexBuffer);

        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(textureCoordinateLocation, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT,
                false,
                0, texCoordBuffer);

        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(textureCoordinateLocation);

        // create and update y texture
        GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0 + 1);
        GLES20.glUniform1i(yTextureLocation, 1);
        GLES20.glTexImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES20.GL_LUMINANCE, this.width,
                this.height, 0, GLES20.GL_LUMINANCE, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, this.yBuffer);
        GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
        GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
        GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

        // create and update uv texture
        GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0 + 2);
        GLES20.glUniform1i(uvTextureLocation, 2);
        GLES20.glTexImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES20.GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA, this.width / 2,
                this.height / 2, 0, GLES20.GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, this.uvBuffer);
        GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
        GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
        GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

        // render image
        GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, indices.length,
                GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indexBuffer);

        GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);
        GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(textureCoordinateLocation);
    }
}

void createShader() {
    int vertexShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER,
            CallConstants.readRawTextFile(context, R.raw.vertex_shader));
    int fragmentShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER,
            CallConstants.readRawTextFile(context, R.raw.fragment_shader));

    shaderProgram = GLES20.glCreateProgram();
    GLES20.glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    GLES20.glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    GLES20.glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);

    GLES20.glUseProgram(shaderProgram);

    int[] linkStatus = new int[1];
    GLES20.glGetProgramiv(shaderProgram, GLES20.GL_LINK_STATUS, linkStatus, 0);
    if (linkStatus[0] != GLES20.GL_TRUE) {
        Log.e("Render", "Could not link program: ");
        Log.e("Render", GLES20.glGetProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram));
        GLES20.glDeleteProgram(shaderProgram);
        shaderProgram = 0;
    }

    // free up no longer needed shader resources
    GLES20.glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
    GLES20.glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);
}

public int loadShader(int type, String shaderCode) {

    int shader = GLES20.glCreateShader(type);

    GLES20.glShaderSource(shader, shaderCode);
    GLES20.glCompileShader(shader);

    return shader;
}
```

}

Comment: Are you sure about setting the ortho on the vertices? You should have a matrix for that and it needs to hold 16 floats. Your buffers hold only 8. Most likely the 3 vertex arrays are tightly packed so the first 2 might work (although that is still an overflow) but the verticesFrontCamera_270_Degree_right should crash due to an overflow or out of bounds. Could you show how you are using these elements later in the code?

Comment: @MaticOblak I have added the full renderer class

Comment: Actually i didn't code this class. My ex team mate did. I tried to use it with a small modification. I have created these vertices to fit multiple case like supporting 3 type data - front camera, back camera and opponent camera data received from internet. I don't know how to rotate on Renderer. tried GLSurfaceView.setRotation(degree) didn't worked. Finally found that change in vertices can rotate or mirror image so handled that situations

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do here but yes, the matrix operation is designed to work on 4x4 matrix which is a buffer of 16 floats. If you want to use this to transform the vertices then you need to create a temporary matrix with this operation and then loop through all your vertices using multiplyMV to transform them. But there is a catch: Your vertices are 2d but the matrix expects 4d so you need to map them to 4d and then back to 2d... It might be easier to construct a matrix and send it into the vertex shader, then do the position multiplication in the shader.

Comment: I have three type of data . one front camera, one back camera and on from opponent camera, Each type data's rotation are different. So i created multiple vertices to rotate them back in normal stage. There must be other way to rotate an image from renderer class, but i don't know. But the image i draw on screen, on prtrait mode: show little tall and on landscape mood show little fat. Not much